# Ethernet switch with ports at the front and back

Tags: ethernet, switch

I am looking for a switch which has at least one port at the back and some 4-5 ports at the front.
Most switches I found either had all ports in the back, with leds on the front. 
The other ones had all ports at the front with power being the only thing that is on the backside.

1 Gbps would be idea.

I found this [switch](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B003CLIOMU), but for some unknown reason they have the power connector at the side and only 100 Mbps ports.

Comment: Can you tell us the reason and maybe we can come up with a creative solution?

Comment: I want to place the switch on the desk. To easily attach devices. Compare it to a USB hub, they have the uplink at the back usually.

Comment: Very crude Google search suggests what you're after is quite expensive or DIN mounted https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ethernet+switch+ports+on+both+sides&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ88aBt-3WAhUK7hoKHWKOB84Q_AUICigB&biw=1604&bih=772

Comment: Can you link it directly? I probably have different search results then you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit 2: There are some products now:
https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0CJ31DLRT as an example. There are various vendors who are all selling the seemingly same device. You can also find it on Aliexpress/ebay.

After some years with no developments on this front I had to do it myself.

TP-Link TL-SG108 with some modifications: Soldered some wires to a RJ45 connector. Cut the metal in the back to insert the port. It's not the finest way to do it, especially as there are still some corners, but at least it works.

Some pictures:

[image: Soldering]

[image: Back]

[image: Connector]

[image: Link]

Answer (score 1):

Black Box has a [5-Port Gigabit Ethernet Switch](https://www.blackbox.com/en-us/store/Detail.aspx/5-Port-Gigabit-Ethernet-Switch-PoE/LPB1205A) with support for Power of Ethernet, however it does cost a pretty penny. Which is closer to what you probably want, with the exception of the power outlet sharing the same side as the 4 port out (but hey, at least it's not on the side!).